# How to sort array by date interval in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array that contains date values. 
I want to sort this array by date, where the date is near(+/-1 days) from now date. 
The array is in this format:

```
Array
(
   [0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 4197
        [date] => Wed, 19 Sep 2015 17:00:00 +0000
    )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4192
            [date] => Sun, 13 Sep 2015 17:00:00 +0000
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4189
            [date] => Sat, 29 Aug 2015 20:00:00 +0000
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4173
            [date] => Wed, 09 Sep 2015 16:00:00 +0000
        )
)
```

I want to get the array sorted in this way:

```
Array
(
   [0] => Array
    (
            [id] => 4173
            [date] => Wed, 09 Sep 2015 16:00:00 +0000
    )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4192
            [date] => Sun, 13 Sep 2015 17:00:00 +0000
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4197
            [date] => Wed, 19 Sep 2015 17:00:00 +0000
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4189
            [date] => Sat, 29 Aug 2015 20:00:00 +0000
        )
)
```

I tried this solution:

```
function sortFunction( $a, $b ) {
    $now = strtotime("+1 day");
    if (($now - strtotime($a["date"])>0) && ($now - strtotime($b["date"])<0))
     {return 0;}
    return strtotime($b["date"]) - strtotime($a["date"]);
}
usort($array, "sortFunction");
```

what I'm doing wrong.
Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking your sort function to accomplish.  How does August end up at the bottom?  Because the date has passed or?

Comment: Question unclear.. You just need a sort or something else??

Comment: Yes the August will end up at the bottom. 
I have some some arrays with dates and I want to sort the arrays by the nearest  (+ or -) from today(now) date. After I have to extract the most 4 nearest array.

Comment: @SubinThomas 
Yes I need a sort but based on the interval date...
Ex: I have 10 dates (05/09/2015 to 14/09/2015), I want to sort the array by near pre and post today date (10/09/2015). 
Hope that this comment can help to understand better what kind off sort I need.

Comment: You have to show real scenario.. Update question.. No codes.. Show some dates and the output you need..

Comment: @SubinThomas , in the question post is a real scenarios with the data that I'm using on my application. 
Anywhere, the code that Ben Plummer has posted is Ok.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming all of inner arrays have a date property with the value formatted consistently, the following solution works:

```
usort($array, function($dateArray1, $dateArray2) {

        $now = new \DateTime();

        $dateA = new \DateTime($dateArray1['date']);
        $dateB = new \DateTime($dateArray2['date']);

        $dayDifferenceA = abs($dateA->diff($now)->days);
        $dayDifferenceB = abs($dateB->diff($now)->days);

        if($dayDifferenceA == $dayDifferenceB) {
            return 0;
        }

        return ($dayDifferenceA < $dayDifferenceB) ? -1 : 1;
    });
```

More checks should be added to ensure date calculations produce correctly formatted results throughout but this is the code in its most basic form.

Comment: Thanks a lot , this is Ok

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help!